# Search for keywords from csv and display results

Tags: powershell, csv

in the CSV Include the softname column

I need to search for a keyword containing 7-zip (or cmm) from it, if it is searched, display its version.

```
$csvtxt = @'
softname,version
7-Zip 18.05 (x64),18.05
Adobe Acrobat DC,18.011.20038
Adobe CMM,1.0
Adobe Flash Player 27 ActiveX,27.0.0.187
Adobe Flash Player 27 PPAPI,27.0.0.187
'@

$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $csvtxt
$soft1 = "7-zip"
$soft2 = "cmm"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `Where-Object` cmdlet here.

```
ConvertFrom-Csv $CSVTxt | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SoftName -match "7-zip|cmm" } | Select-Object -Property Version
```

Read more about Where-Object [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Your code is very short and easy to understand, thank you for your thanks.

Comment: I want to get the version value directly, is there a simpler code?
---
(ConvertFrom-Csv $CSVTxt | Where -FilterScript { $_.SoftName -match "7-zip" } | Select -Property Version).version
---

Answer (score 1):

you can use the way that `-match` works against a collection. that will give the objects that match the regex pattern.

what it does ...

- create the data set to work with by faking reading in a CSV file
- create the software list to check for
- convert that list to an escaped regex OR pattern
- run the `-match` operator against the collection using the pattern above
- save the results to the `$FoundSoftware` collection
- show it on screen

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
softname,version
7-Zip 18.05 (x64),18.05
Adobe Acrobat DC,18.011.20038
Adobe CMM,1.0
Adobe Flash Player 27 ActiveX,27.0.0.187
Adobe Flash Player 27 PPAPI,27.0.0.187
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$SoftwareList = @(
    '7-zip'
    'cmm'
    )
$Regex_SL = $SoftwareList.ForEach({[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$FoundSoftware = $InStuff -match $Regex_SL
# if you dislike the way that "-match" works directly on an array, use the next line 
#$FoundSoftware = $InStuff.Where({$_.SoftName -match $Regex_SL})

$FoundSoftware
```

output ...

```
softname          version
--------          -------
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) 18.05  
Adobe CMM         1.0
```

if you want only the bare names, you can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to get that. [*grin*]

Comment: thank you very much for your help,I don't know much about regular expressions, I think the following code is easier to understand.

Comment: @tianyi - you are most welcome! as for choosing one or the other of the offered solutions ... you will need to maintain it, so _always_ select the one that makes the most sense to you - and works! [*grin*]